# Slutsy Equation and Income effect

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, slutsky-equation

Does the Slutsky equation always assume optimal levels of our variables, hence Marshellian demand = Hiscksian demand $x = h$ as indeed this is how the Slutsky is derived?

I originally thought this mean't the following two equations were equal:

> $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial p_j} = \frac{\partial h_i}{\partial p_j} - x_j \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial m}$

> $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial p_j} = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial p_j} - x_j \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial m}$

However I have now reasoned to myself why this isn't the case. Please let me know if I'm correct.

This would give us: $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial p_j} - \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial p_j} = - x_j \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial m} = 0$

- I assume this must be invalid and we cannot swap the partial dedicative or Mareshellian with respect for price, with HIcksian with respect to price (Unless Income effect = 0).
- I assume this is because the Hicksian is just the substitution effect, where as Marshellian Is Substitution and Income effect, which is the whole point of the slutsky equation.
- If we do make these partial derivatives equivalent, then essentially we are saying there is no income effect. I.e. The Marshellian demand is also just the substitution effect. This is exactly what we get with the income effect = 0 in the equation.

**Question**

- What's some intuition for the fact that the substitution effect is given just by the derivative with respect to price. But the Income effect is the derivative multiplied by $x$
- I suppose what i'm asking here is why do we have  an equation about rate of change $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial p_j}$, do we have the term rate of change multiplied $x$ i.e. the term $x_j \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial m}$ which feels like actual change.